# i have to cin my name to enter my resources how do i do that

Tags: c++, console-input

cin << name << endl;
cout >> "my name is " << name << endl;

Comment: `if (ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes")  return getchoice2();` -- Look at your code carefully -- you are returning an `int` (the choice) from a function that returns a `double`.  In addition, you are recursively calling `getmusclemass()` instead of using the proper looping constructs.  Your `getmusclemass()` function should not be doing any input or output -- its job should be to accept values as parameters, and returns a value based on calculations, not I/O.  As a matter of fact, maybe you should learn what function parameters are, since your program lacks any use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

When you say `cin >> smth`, you want to get precisely smth, nothing more. End-line marker is not part of it, so it's not consumed. Unless you would have a special type for line, but there is no such thing in standard library.

When you use `getline` you say you want to get a line. A line is string that ends with `\n`, the ending is integral part of it.

So the problem is that `std::cin` leaves an end-line `\n` character in buffer.

---

**Example**

```
std::cin >> smth;

+---+---+---+---+---+----+
|'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|'\n'|      // In smth will be "Hello"
+---+---+---+---+---+----+

+----+
|'\n'|                          // But new-line character stays in buffer
+----+

std::cin >> smth2;              // Its same like you would press just an 'enter', so smth2 is empty
```

---

**Solution**

- Use `std::cin.getline`

or

- Use `std::cin >> smth;` + `std::cin.ignore();`

Comment: No, all the standard `operator>>` will skip whitespace before reading into a variable. That will consume the `'\n'` left in the buffer. It is only if you mix `>>` and `getline` that you might get an empty line.